# is there any android build options for changing the memory limit?

Tags: android, memory, build

I heard there is a memory limitation for each app, about 24 MB in gingerbread

how can I change this limit value at android building process?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://tordtech.blogspot.com/2009/09/memory-limit-on-android.html) might help.

Comment: In gingerbread, I cannot find same code in that Blog. but when I searched "CUSTOM_RUNTIME_HEAP_MAX", I found some code about the value of heap size limitation. I'll add another comment about results later. thank you.